# Why is Material 2 Autocomplete interfered by Browser autocomplete?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

I added following

```
<mat-form-field id="recipe-form__nations" >
    <input type="text" matInput ngModel name="nation" placeholder="Nation" autocomplete="off" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete  #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let nation of nationalities" [value]="">
            {{ nation }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then when I click on input I See

[image]

Notice 2 entries are added, and yellow highlighting when selecting options I didn't list? This isn't angular material 2. The rest are (American, French, etc..)

Tried adding a `autocomplete="off"` which resolved the input field for name, but didn't help here.